# jquery - pattern matching

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I've been trying to use the jquery match() function, but I'm not able to get anything I try to work...

Basically, I'm trying to match any string between parentheses:

(sample)
(pokemon)
(su54gar99)

... etc.

Tried this (the latest attempt... not sure how many I've gone through at this point...)

```
$('.acf').each(function() {
                var ac = $(this);
                ac.data('changed', false);
                ac.data('alias', 'ac-real-');
                ac.data('rx',  /\s*\(\s+\)\s*/i);
                ac.data('name', ac.attr('name'));
                ac.data('id', ac.attr('id'));
                ac.data('value', ac.val());
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `\s` ? It matches any whitespace character

Use a regular expression like below:

```
\(.+\)
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out like 1 minutes after I posted... Thank you, though!

Comment: Never use the dot when there is a more precise expression (in this case: `[^()]`). The expression: `\(.+\)` fails if there are multiple sets of parentheses. Note that the lazy dot version: `\(.+?\)` also fails if the parentheses are nested. Use: `\([^()]*\)` to safely match only innermost sets of parentheses.

Comment: It was just a suggestion to correct what was wrong. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest your fault is, that "\s" only stands for whitespace characters, but not for normal characters ;).

Second, for finding EACH and not stopping after 1 result, add the "g" (for global) modifier.

Try something like this:

```
var text = "(sample) (pokemon) (su54gar99)";
var found = text.match(/\s*\(([a-z,0-9]*)\)/ig);
$.each(found, function(i, v) {
    alert(i+" = "+v);
});
```

Works with at least the given example ;).

TIP: Visit: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
Best side for learning RegEx, in my opinion :P.

Comment: Curses, beat me. `/^\(.|\d*?\)$/` <- any downfalls?